# How to adjust list style Background Image position angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Is there a way to adjust the position of `list-style` `background-image`?

When I use padding for list items the image will stay stuck at the top at its position and won't move with padding.

```html
<li class="list-list-item" [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : (reports.response_rate_7day_change > 0) ? getIncrease():  getDecrease() }" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;  padding: 3px 0px 3px 10px; list-style: none; margin: 0; vertical-align: middle;">
</li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your style

```
background-position: center;
```

the complete implementation will be

```
<li class="list-list-item" [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : (reports.response_rate_7day_change > 0) ? getIncrease():  getDecrease() }" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;  padding: 3px 0px 3px 10px; list-style: none; margin: 0; vertical-align: middle;">
</li>
```